# How to keep information of the WCF server and WCF clients when the server gets failed and restarts

Tags: wcf

In WCF how to handle this scenario:
Suppose that a server with callback capability is running with multiple clients. What if the server breaks accidentally and needs to restart? How can the server reload the client's information without the need for the clients to reload? Which information of the server should be saved in clients to get loaded again easily?

Answer (score 1):

Unhandled exceptions in the wcf service can cause the communication channel to fail and sessions to be lost. To continue the communication, you need to create a new session instance.

A communication error causes wcf to raise a Faulted event on the client, and you can add the error type to the SOAP error sent to the client if you feel appropriate.